# get_the_date() not repeating date

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<div class="page-content">

<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
while ( have_posts() ) :
the_post();
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<br />
<?php
the_content();
echo get_the_date('l,d');
endwhile;
endif;
?>

</div>
```

This example is not repeating the date for each post. I am using the code in a page template, namely services-template.php and I have read the note that states get_the_date() will repeat the date for each post. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is it doing? Is it behaving like `the_date` instead? What version of Wordpress is installed? Have you tried passing the post or postId to get_the_date to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: WP version: 3.9.3  
Instead of repeating for each post it only list one time for all post.

Comment: is the date showing up in any of the posts?

Comment: Yes, one time at the top of the page, before the_content().

Comment: I am still trying to figure this out, does anyone have an idea of why this isn't working. Or has this question been answered on SO already?

Comment: some functions only run once per page within the loop, this is likely one of them. try it with the $post id defined

Answer (score 0):

I could not make the original code work, I do not know all the internal workings of Wordpress but my guess is that what ever variable holds post data (most likely $post) was empty. The following code did what I was looking to do. Again I am using this code on a custom page. services-template.php.

```
$args = array( 'category' => '4' );

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li><h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2></li>';
        echo '<li>' . get_the_date() . '</li>';
        echo '<li>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</li>';
        the_tags();
        echo '<br /><br />';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();

;
?>
```